# How to change the style to a navbar item when on a specific part of my page?

Tags: css, navbar, new-operator

I'm a new web developer (started a couple weeks ago) and I'm building my first website with Bootstrap. For this I made a sticky navbar that stays on top even if you scroll down and I want it to highlight the part of the page you are at (ex. if im in the Contact me section of the web I want the text "Contact me" in the navigation bar to have a different color) but I have not been able to since CSS doesn't have conditionals (I'm a big Excel lover so it's been confusing).

It may be pretty simple but I'm a newbie on this.

Thank you!

Every web section has an id (#landing, #aboutme, #contactme, etc) and I tried putting in the CSS:

#contactme:hover{ .... but that's as far as I go since I don't know how to call another id and apply on action on that. My idea was to create an if/then (ex. if you hover on that section on the page then highlight the contact me text on the nav bar.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do that with just CSS. Maybe with a CSS extension. But definitely possible with JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, this requires Javascript, the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) has been designed for requirements like this.

Comment: Thank you!! I'm learning Javascript right now so I'll be able to do this soon.